# What is the speed of this function $m(t) =0.1t^2+3t$ at the very last moment

Tags: calculus

Suppose a runner runs $400$ meters and this is the function at which he runs at $m(t) =0.1t^2+3t$ I know $t=50$ when it's $400 \text{ m}$ what I want know is how can I know the speed at which he was going at at the very last moment. I've tried looking for the answer but I can't find anything. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative of m(t). If m(t) represents position, m'(t) represents velocity!

$m'(t) = 0.2t + 3$.

$m'(50) = 0.2(50)+3 = 13$ meters/sec.